# Is there a standard method to have unique values in SQL table per parent record

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

What I would like to do is have SQL maintain the integrity of my data as opposed to doing it through my application. I would like to have it that the SQL will not let me add duplicate items **per price list**.

If I have 3 tables "PriceList", "Prices" and "InventoryItems"

Columns

**PriceList:** ID, Name

**InventoryItem:** ID, SKU, Name

**Prices:** ID, ListID, ItemID, Price

I cannot put a unique on the prices.itemid as this wont allow me to add the same item to multiple price lists.

| ID | ListID | ItemID | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 106 | 25.35 |
| 2 | 1 | 122 | 45.85 |
| 3 | 1 | 122 | 33.24 |
| 4 | 1 | 136 | 86.33 |

In the example above I would like there to be a constraint which will prevent the item on line 3 from being added as there is already an itemID 122 linked to ListID 1

Can this be done in SQL with relations/index or some other methodology.

Comment: Do you mean a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`?

Comment: Add it as a unique index? https://www.google.com/search?q=unique+index&oq=unique+index&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l9.3233j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Another option is to make ListID, ItemID a composite primary key and remove the ID column surrogate key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `UNIQUE` constraint, as in:

```
alter table my_table
add constraint uq1 unique (ListID, ItemID);
```